# jQuery - switching DIVs based on radio selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, radio-button

What is the best way to go about switching divs depending on the radio selection? I'd like it to do a switch if any radios are already selected at the start and hide all divs if no selection.

My current code only does switches on change (using input id as class name of id currently, if any better methods please do say so)

```
$(function () {
    var shippDescriptions = $('div#shipping_descs > div');

    shippDescriptions.hide();

    $('input[type=radio]', '#shipping_inputs').change(function () {
        shippDescriptions.hide().filter('.' + $(this).attr('id')).show();
    });
});
```

What is the best approach? Extract and set the code in the change() to something and run it twice?

Also, this won't hide the divs until the page is loaded correct?

Comment: That choice of `shippDescriptions` is gonna cause problems for someone maintaining your code. Remove a "p" for someone's sake!

Comment: This won't hide the div's until the page has loaded. I typically do this the reverse. Hide the divs (display:none), then have javascript toggle them visible if they should be. I think it's far more normal to see more elements added to your screen, than to all of the sudden see them taken away during a load.

Comment: Yes this will hide the divs only after page fully loads. But you can render them invisible from the beginning!

Comment: But *should* you use CSS to hide the elements? What happens if (and I know it's a vanishingly small number of people browsing with) JavaScript's turned off? Doesn't the whole experience break in that case?

Comment: @DavidThomas - that is what I was thinking -- currently though I'd have to restructure my form so the divs (containing extra form elements depending on radio selection) would be coherent/grouped with their respective radios -- still unsure on what I'll do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below approach, It has 1 restriction that the value of the radio options and the div id of the each shipping desc has a relation. but I believe it shouldn't be a problem.

Also I prefer hiding all the desc in html/css so that it doesn't show onload.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script> 
        $(function () {
            var shippDescriptions = $('div#shipping_descs > div.shipping_desc');

            //one time - onload
            var selectedOption = $(':radio[name="r1"]:checked').val();              
            $('#S'+selectedOption).show();

            $('input[type=radio]', '#shipping_inputs').change(function () {

                //hide all shipping desc
                shippDescriptions.hide();

                //show shipping desc for selected option
                $('#S'+ $(this).val()).show();
            });
        });

    </script>
    <style>
        .hidden { display: none; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="shipping_inputs">
        <input type="radio" value="1" name="r1" />S1
        <input type="radio" value="2" name="r1" />S2
        <input type="radio" value="3" name="r1" checked="checked" />S3
        <input type="radio" value="4" name="r1" />S4
        <input type="radio" value="5" name="r1" />S5
    </div>
    <div id="shipping_descs" >
        <div id="S1" class="shipping_desc hidden" >S1 Desc</div>
        <div id="S2" class="shipping_desc hidden" >S2 Desc</div>
        <div id="S3" class="shipping_desc hidden" >S3 Desc</div>
        <div id="S4" class="shipping_desc hidden" >S4 D esc</div>
        <div id="S5" class="shipping_desc hidden" >S5 Desc</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your correct once the page loads it will hide the div. Depending on the client computer you "shouldn't" see the image on page load. it may be better to include `display:none` in your CSS for the divs if you are concerned about it being visible.

As for your switching question you will need to set it twice

```
$(function () {
    var shippDescriptions = $('div#shipping_descs > div');
    shippDescriptions.each(function(){
       if ($(this).attr('class') == $('input[type="radio"]:checked').attr('id'))
           $(this).show().siblings().hide();
    });
    $('input[type=radio]', '#shipping_inputs').change(function () {
       shippDescriptions.hide().filter('.' + $(this).attr('id')).show();
    });
```

Should be a good start to getting it working